# ReactJS passing a state value to onClick event function as a parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component :-

```
const PartTable = (props) => {
   const [previousPart, setPreviousPart] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("read")) {
      const decodedjwtToken = jwt(localStorage.getItem("read"));
      setPreviousPart(decodedjwtToken.p);
    }
  }, []);

  function handlePartSelection(previousSelection) {
    console.log("previouspart", previousSelection); //Here its returning undefined 
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
              <div onClick={() => handlePartSelection(previousPart)} >
                Select part
               </div>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PartTable;
```

i am trying to pass the "previousPart" state as a parameter for handlePartSelection function, in console log when i tried to check the passed value, its return undefined.

How can i read the previousPart state in handlePartSelection function ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215062/discussion-on-question-by-q8root-reactjs-passing-a-state-value-to-onclick-event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const PartTable = (props) => {
   const [previousPart, setPreviousPart] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("read")) {
      const decodedjwtToken = jwt(localStorage.getItem("read"));
      setPreviousPart(decodedjwtToken.p);
    }
  }, []);

  const handlePartSelection = () => {
    console.log("previouspart", previousPart); //Here its returning undefined 
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
              <div onClick={handlePartSelection} >
                Select part
               </div>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PartTable;
```

I hope it helps